# Complexity of (for (int i=0 ; i< pow(2,n) ; i++)

Tags: time, time-complexity

I have a problem, how can I determine the complexity of this algorithm?

```
int pow (int a, int b) {
   int result=1;
   while (b>0) {
     result = result*a;
     b = b-1;
   }
   return result;
}

void bar (int n) {
   for (int i=0; i<pow(2,n); i++)
       printf("%d", i);
}
```

The solution from the professor was that `pow(a,b)` has the complexity of `O(n)`, and because the for-loop has the complexity `O(n)` and `O(2^n)` for pow, then at the end the total complexity of bar is `O(n*2^n)`.

But why `2^n`?  I don't understand that.  Please help me because I have an Exam.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it to you step by step.
The `for loop` runs for how many times? `pow(2,n)` times right?
 So, pow(2,n) is nothing but 2 power n, and hence the first complexity we have is O(2^n).
Coming to the complexity of `pow(a,b)` function.
By looking at it, we can say that the loop runs for how many times? 'b' times. Hence the time complexity of pow(a,b) is completely depended on 'b' and hence it is O(b).

In the algorithm, b is nothing but n. And hence, we have our second complexity as O(n).
So, now we have a loop that runs for pow(2,n) times, and every time, it runs O(b) = O(n) times. So we multiply the complexities and hence it becomes, O(n*2^n)
Hope I was somewhat clear.

Comment: thank you very much now is clear but can you help me with another Example please :

Show that the recursion equation for the worst case T (n) = T (n-1) + T (0) + THETA (n) has the solution T (n) = THETA (n ^ 2), i have tried to use the Master-theorem but didn't success

Answer (score 0):

The function `pow` has the complexity of O(n), as you stated.

However, the function `bar` can be looked at as:

```
void bar (int n) {
    int m = pow(2,n);   // pow is called only once
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
       printf("%d", i);
}
```

Which means that the complexity of the function `bar` is **O(n + 2^n)**, which is **O(2^n)**.